# AWS EMR Phoenix Kerberos not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, hbase, kerberos, apache-phoenix

I am trying to get Phoenix work with kerberos.
Kerberos realm are setup , i am able to generate tickets from keytab /etc/hbase.keytab

but phoenix sqlline client is giving following error

Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations (state=,code=0)

I have done following changes

```
# Issue ticket for principal

kinit -t /etc/hbase.keytab hbase/HOSTNAME.RealmName@RealmName


<!-- Configuring Phoenix Kerberos Properties in Hbase_site.xml --> 

<property>
        <name>phoenix.queryserver.kerberos.principal</name>
        <value>hbase/_HOST@RealmName</value>
  </property>

  <property>
        <name>phoenix.queryserver.kerberos.keytab</name>
        <value>/etc/hbase.keytab</value>
   </property>

  <property>
        <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
        <value>/hbase-secure</value>
   </property>   

  <property>
        <name>phoenix.queryserver.keytab.file</name>
        <value>/etc/hbase.keytab</value>
  </property>

   <property>
        <name>phoenix.queryserver.http.keytab.file</name>
        <value>/etc/hbase.keytab</value>
   </property>

   <property>
        <name>phoenix.queryserver.kerberos.http.principal</name>
        <value>hbase/_HOST@RealmName</value>
   </property>   

   <property>
        <name>phoenix.queryserver.dns.nameserver</name>
        <value>HOSTNAME.RealmName</value>
   </property>   

   <property>
        <name>phoenix.queryserver.dns.interface</name>
        <value>eth0</value>
   </property>



#   Set hbase conf path (This seems to be a bug in EMR. This should be set by default.)
                sudo vi ~/.bashrc
add        “export HBASE_CONF_DIR=/etc/hbase/conf/ “
                source ~/.bashrc
```

## Starting Phoenix Client

```
/usr/lib/phoenix/bin/sqlline.py HOSTNAME.RealmName:2181:/hbase-secure:hbase/HOSTNAME.RealmName@RealmName:/etc/hbase.keytab
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in EMR 5.11 
The issue was resolved after setting HBASE_CONF_DIR in ~/.bashrc

```
sudo vi ~/.bashrc
add “export HBASE_CONF_DIR=/etc/hbase/conf/“
source ~/.bashrc
```

run phoenix

```
/usr/lib/phoenix/bin/sqlline.py
```